# Calling triggers on replicated table when reinitalising from snapshot

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2014, transactional-replication, snapshot

I noticed my triggers weren't being fired after a subscriber was reinitialised. Is there a configuration to allow this functionality.

Currently my setting for 'Action if name is in use' is 'Delete data' so I know my triggers aren't being deleted after the table is reinitialised.

I have already confirmed that the trigger works by manualling inserting a row in my publisher database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

re-creating the triggers after I run the snap does the trick for me.

The way I do it and it has always been worked is the following:

Before I run the [snapshot](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/239667/22336) and [reinitialize](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/237146/22336) the subscriptions,
I go to the subscription databases and script out all the [permissions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/260200/22336), [triggers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/214503/22336), [synonyms](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/191824/22336), and in some cases the indexes (when indexes in the subscription are different than the [indexes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/136269/22336) in the publisher).

when running and applying the snapshot it basically will re-create all the tables (that are part of the publication)

so if you do a `select * from sys.tables` you will see the `create date` of those tables.

Basically right after you run the snap, you then need to apply all those scripts you previously generated as I mentioned before (permissions, triggers, synonyms, indexes). there is even a place you can set up the script to be run immediately after you run the snap so it does it automatically for you.

Just make sure you have all the permissions set to read a file that is saved somewhere.

[image]